# Why does my code to import numeric data from a text file into a 2D array does not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, data-import

The data in the text file is written in the form 
0 23 4 23 16 ..  and so on.

I would like to store it in a 5*5 static array. But when I try and output the array the output is a garbled mess of numbers, not the data I want to import.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char A[5][5];
int i = 0, j =0;
int main()
{

  ifstream fin("File.txt");
  if (fin.is_open())
  {
   cout << "The file has been opened successfully" << endl;
    while(!fin.eof())
      {
        for(i = 0 ;  i<5; i++)
        {
            for(j =0; j<5; j++)
            {
               fin.get(A[i][j]);
             }
        }
      }
     }


     return 0; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your "File.txt" contains :

```
0 23 45 58 36 5 425 442 4
```

these specific 25 (5*5) characters you put. (Yeah, spaces do count as characters, and in ASCII tables it is actually the 32nd character). If you run this function on it :

```
for (size_t i = 0;i<5;++i)
    for(size_t j = 0;j<5;++j)
    {   cout << A[i][j] << setw (4);
        cout << int (A[i][j]) << endl;
    }
```

You will get this output :

```
0  48
   32
2  50
3  51
   32
4  52
5  53
   32
5  53
8  56
   32
3  51
6  54
   32
5  53
   32
4  52
2  50
5  53
   32
4  52
4  52
2  50
   32
4  52
```

Written in the first row : the character corresponding to your string (in File.txt, and if you check what i put, its the same vertically), and in the second row, the associated integer values.
I guess this might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to input the data number by number. 
However, the function you're calling: 
`std::istream& get (char& c)` is taking data character by character, as per:

(1) single character
Extracts a single character from the stream.
The character is either returned (first signature), or set as the value of its argument (second signature).

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

For input white-space separated input, consider using the normal >> operator like this:

```
std::string word;
while (file >> word)
{
    ...
}
```